# Why is RotatingFileHandler not appending to file

Tags: python, logging

Consider the following code:

```
def setup_logging(logdir=None, scrnlog=True, txtlog=True, loglevel=logging.DEBUG):
logdir = os.path.abspath(logdir)

if not os.path.exists(logdir):
    os.mkdir(logdir)

log = logging.getLogger('pobsync')
log.setLevel(loglevel)

log_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s :: %(message)s")

if txtlog:
    txt_handler = RotatingFileHandler(os.path.join(logdir, "pobsync.log"), mode='a', maxBytes=100000)
    txt_handler.doRollover()
    txt_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    log.addHandler(txt_handler)

if scrnlog:
    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    log.addHandler(console_handler)
```

The logging itself works perfectly; I just call my script with log.LEVEL() and it logs nicely to the defined logfile, just as I want it. However, for some reason my logs aren't appending at all, but overwrites the logfile each time instead of appending to it like it should.
If I use backupCount=$number in RotatingFileHandler, it still doesn't append, but makes a new logfile (in the expected RotatingFileHandler pattern) up to $number and then rotates them away eventually.

I'm very likely overlooking something here, but for the love of me I can't find the problem at all.

I hope someone here can help me out and hit me with a cluebat, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing a rollover right after setting up the handler. You aren't overwriting the log, you are just archiving the current log to pobsunc-1.log. Just remove

```
txt_handler.doRollover()
```

See [rotatingfilehandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler)

(update)

Since `backupCount` defaults to `0`, your call to doRollover doesn't create `pobsync-1.log`, it really does delete it. Rotating logs are more useful if you set `backupCount` greater than `0`.

Comment: Yes, this was exactly what was wrong and I have honestly no idea how I could've overlooked this, I blame it on it being friday at the time of asking and me wanting to go home.
Thanks for the insight!